# 0 leading number format in google sheet in google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

```
<script>
  function jump01(field, autoMove){
    if (field.value.length >= field.maxLength){
      document.getElementById("text-number").value.toString();
      document.getElementById(autoMove).focus();
      document.getElementById("money-amount").value = "";
    }
  }

  function afterButtomClicked(){
    var num = document.getElementById("text-number");
    var am =  document.getElementById("money-amount");
    var rowData = {number: num.value, amount: am.value};
    google.script.run.addNewRow(rowData);
    document.getElementById("text-number").value = "";
  }

  document.getElementById("mainButtom").addEventListener("click",afterButtomClicked);

  function focusInput() { 
    document.getElementById("text-number").focus();
  } 
 
</script>
```

That is how in google script code.
The problem is I can't put 00 or 01 in google sheet cell. or 0 leading number in cell form.
if possible I want to know how to write like 84 number to 48 to 84. or 123 to 132 213 231 321 312 in a different cell by typing + number.
I was using custom user form(custom HTML user form) in google sheet.

```
function addNewRow(rowData) {
    const currentDate = new Date();
    
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Name 9");
    ws.appendRow([rowData.number,rowData.amount,rowData.amount * 44,currentDate]);
}
```

that is add new row function

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please show the `addNewRow()` Google Apps Script code instead of the client-side JavaScript code.

Comment: ``function addNewRow(rowData) {
  
const currentDate = new Date();

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Name 9");
ws.appendRow([rowData.number,rowData.amount,rowData.amount * 44,currentDate]);

}``

Comment: Edited the answer to add example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be best to use [Range.setNumberFormat()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat) in the `addNewRow()` function, like this:

```
function addNewRow(rowData) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Name 9');
  const data = [[rowData.number, rowData.amount, rowData.amount * 44, new Date()]];
  const formats = [['00.00', '00.00', '00.00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm']];
  const appendRange = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, data.length, data[0].length);
  appendRange.setValues(data).setNumberFormats(formats);
}
```

The quick but ugly way is to coerce the data to text strings and prefix with an apostrophe, like this:

`ws.appendRow([rowData.number,rowData.amount,rowData.amount * 44,currentDate].map(value => "'" + String(value)));`